# Nothing gets written while writing multiple rows into multiple sheets in a workbook using exceljs

Tags: javascript, exceljs

I am trying to read a log file and then write the data into workbook containing multiple worksheets on the basis of set of conditions. I addRow to sheet whenever I encounter a particular node's data. Nothing is written in final workbook. The problem might be of scoping but I am not able to debug it properly.

I tried adding rows to sheets outside lineReader function. It works correctly and data is written in workbook. However, I need to go through  the conditions and that is where problem comes.

Comment: you probably want to put this all in a try catch and see whether there is an error.

Comment: I tried using exception handling and found that the no error has been thrown.

Comment: I tried copying your items from the log and splitting them. It may be because of the transition between places, but there are not tabs, so MsgArray had just one entry and MsgArray[2] was empty.

Comment: But I see what was trouble here. I suggest line = line.replace(/\s+/g, ' '); before splitting on space.

Comment: I have added the snapshot of debug output. msgArray2 indexes are correctly printed even without adding  line.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');.

Comment: I tried giving arbitrary input to sheet1 inside lineReader function. Even that also not work. That basically means addRow is not working on sheets     ```sheet1.addRow({ALL_CPU: 1, ALL_LPM: 2, ALL_TX:3, ALL_RX:4});```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194183/discussion-between-av92-and-jeremy-kahan).

Comment: Sorry. I am out of ideas. This looks like it would be in the wheelhouse of user:5461205 (@Dirk Reichel)

Comment: The code has some problem thus I wrote python script to do the same. That works. Thaks for the efforts.